# Difference between Test Send and Send in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can anyone clarify what is the difference test Send and Actual Send?

Thanks

Comment: test sends are not recorded on the Send Log data extension

Answer (score 0):

A test send allows you to select a record from any list or data extension but send to another email address. This allows you to see how any AMPscript is rendering.

Actual send is just a regular send to the records specified in the list or data extension.

Comment: Thanks!! Thats something i know. But is there anything related to functionality? currently with test sends i am not able to use Web Version link on the email templates? Is this working as designed?

Comment: With test sends-all functionality SHOULD work. Are you getting an error when clicking the link from the test send?